# Getting integer size in bits

Tags: c++, c, integer, hex, ifstream

I need to know whether an integer is 32 bits long or not (I want to know if it's exactly 32 bits long (8 hexadecimal characters)).

How could I achieve this in C++? Should I do this with the hexadecimal representation or with the unsigned int one?

My code is as follows:

```cpp
mistream.open("myfile.txt");

if(mistream)
{
    for(int i=0; i<longArray; i++)
    {
        mistream >> hex >> datos[i];        
    }
}

mistream.close();
```

Where `mistream` is of type `ifstream`, and `datos` is an unsigned int array.

Comment: use `<limits.h>` and compute `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT`  or test `INT_MAX/INT_MIN`

Comment: I am not sure whether you want to know how many bits a variable of type `int` uses in your platform, or how many bits are necessary to represent a specifi integer value. In integer might take 32 bits but it takes only 1 bit to represent the value 0.

Comment: A non-portable way to do it is to use non-standard intrinsics. Most machines has instructions to count leading zeros or leading redundant sign bits.

Comment: To be clear: are you interested in knowing if the _type_ is 32 bits or if the _value_ is between `power(2,31) and power(2,32)-1` or something else?

Comment: Yes @chux I am interested in knowing if the value is between power(2, 31) and power(2, 32) - 1. Could you help me? Thank you

Comment: Just a pedantic note that a number can be expressed in fewer than 32 bits and still need "8 hexadecimal characters," for example `0x1000'0000` which only uses 29 bits.  Consider removing the remark about 8 hex chars from your question.

Answer (score 24):

```
std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits
```

is a static integer constant (or constexpr in C++11) giving the number of bits (since unsigned is stored in base 2, it gives binary digits).

You need to `#include <limits>` to get this, and you'll notice [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) that this gives the same value as Thomas' answer (while also being generalizable to other primitive types)

---

For reference (you changed your question after I answered), every integer of a given type (eg, `unsigned`) in a given program *is exactly the same size*.

What you're now asking is not the *size* of the integer in bits, because that never varies, but whether the top bit is set. You can test this trivially with

```
bool isTopBitSet(uint32_t v) {
  return v & 0x80000000u;
}
```

(replace the unsigned hex literal with something like `T{1} << (std::numeric_limits<T>::digits-1)` if you want to generalise to unsigned T other than `uint32_t`).

Answer (score 8):

As already hinted in a comment by @chux, you can use a combination of the `sizeof` operator and the `CHAR_BIT` macro constant.  The former tells you (at compile-time) the size (in multiples of `sizeof(char)` aka bytes) of its argument type.  The latter is the number of bits to the byte (usually 8).

You can encapsulate this nicely into a function template.

```
#include <climits>   // CHAR_BIT
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t
#include <iostream>  // std::cout, std::endl

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t
bit_size() noexcept
{
  return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << bit_size<int>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << bit_size<long>() << std::endl;
}
```

On my implementation, it outputs 32 and 64.

Since the function is a `constexpr`, you can use it in static contexts, such as in `static_assert<bit_size<int>() >= 32, "too small");`.

Comment: `struct Foo { int a : 5; int b : 13; };` Is there a way to `bit_size<Foo::a>` to return 5?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#include <climits>

unsigned int bits_per_byte = CHAR_BIT;
unsigned int bits_per_integer = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int);
```

The identifier `CHAR_BIT` represents the number of bits in a `char`.

The `sizeof` returns the number of char locations occupied by the integer.

Multiplying them gives us the number of bits for an integer.

Comment: What's the value of CHAR_BITS? I mean, the exact value, or, if not, how can I get it? Thank you

Comment: This works in practice, but is not guaranteed. The standard allows `int` to use 29 bits.

Comment: The macro is named `CHAR_BIT` (singular) and it is defined in `climits`, not `cstdint`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Comment: I am doing it like this: unsigned int bits_per_integer = CHAR_BITS * sizeof(myarray[i]), but it always returns 32. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edited per comment of @5gon12eder.

Comment: What is the declaration of `myarray`?  What platform are you using?

Comment: I am obtaining myarray from a file. It has 6 integers

Comment: 32 is the correct number of bits in an int on a 32bit architecture machine.  @ChristopherCreutzig, where did you get 29 bits?

Comment: if `myarray` is an int array, and int is 32 bits on your system (which is almost the case on modern systems) then obviously `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(myarray[i])` would always return 32 which is the number of bits in an `int` or `myarray[i]`. What else do you expect?

Comment: @user3629249 that's allowed by the standard. It only specifies the minimum range for types.

Comment: `sizeof(expression)` only looks at the compile-time *type* of the expression, not the runtime *value*.

Answer (score 0):

OP said "if it's exactly 32 bits long (8 hexadecimal characters)" and further with ".. interested in knowing if the value is between power(2, 31) and power(2, 32) - 1".  So it is a little fuzzy on negative 32-bit numbers.

Certainly OP wants to know the result based on the value and not the type.

```
bool integer_is_32_bits_long(int x) = 
    // cope with 32-bit int
    ((INT_MAX == 0x7FFFFFFF) && (x < 0)) ||
    // larger 32-bit int
    ((INT_MAX >  0x7FFFFFFF) && (x >= 0x80000000) && (x <= 0xFFFFFFFF));
```

Of course if `int` is 16-bit, then the result is always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if it's exactly 32 bits long (8 hexadecimal characters)
>
> I am interested in knowing if the value is between power(2, 31) and power(2, 32) - 1

So you want to know if the upper bit is set? Then you can simply test if the number is negative:

```
bool upperBitSet(int x)
{
    return x < 0;
}
```

For unsigned numbers, you can simply shift left and back right and then check if you lost data:

```
bool upperBitSet(unsigned x)
{
    return (x << 1 >> 1) != x;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way probably is to check if the 32nd bit is set:

```
bool isReally32bitsLong(uint32_t in) {
  return (in >> 31)!=0;
}

bool isExactly32BitsLong(uint64_t in) {
  return ((in >> 31)!=0) && ((in >> 32) == 0);
}
```

Comment: `1UL << 32` is potential an issue.

Comment: No, it's obviously an issue.

Comment: @user3528438 `1UL << 32` is not a problem should `unsigned long` uncharacteristically be wider than 32-bit.

Comment: No, it's not. But I changed the code to also work on exotic systems with `sizeof(unsigned long) < 64`. ;-}

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig: Exotic?  You mean like Windows?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Right, that was the name. ;-}}

Comment: @MooingDuck Why windows? Almost all implementation on all 32bit machines uses 32bit `long`

Comment: @user3528438: Specifically, _Visual Studio_ (The compiler used to compile almost all Windows programs) uses 32 bit longs when compiling for 64 bit machines.  Clang and G++ both use 64 bit longs when compiling for 64 bit machines.  `long` is a language thing, so what matters is the compiler, not the hardware.

Comment: This causes undefined behavior with 16-bit integers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What does? The code in my answer only uses integers  of specified width now, no 16 bit integers anywhere.